# MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to create two entities (student, university) with a unidirectional `@ManyToOne` relationship between them. University can have many students.

I don't want to save them seperately, i want to save student and university should be saved because of `@Cascade`.

During saving second student i get exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I don't know how to resolve that problem.

My code:

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private University university;

    public Student(String name, University university) {
        this.name = name;
        this.university = university;
    }

    public Student() {
    }
}

@Entity
public class University {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public University(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public University() {
    }
}

    @Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student,Long> {
}



@SpringBootApplication
public class App implements CommandLineRunner
{
    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;
    @Autowired
    private UniversityRepository universityRepository;

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        Student student = new Student("pawel", new University(1L,"pw"));
        Student student1 = new Student("gawel", new University(1L,"pw"));
        studentRepository. save(student);
        studentRepository.save(student1);
    }
}
```

I explored that if beside university reference i set student id manually than everything works.

code that works:

```
  @Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String nazwa;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private University university;

    public Student(Long id,String nazwa, University university) {
        this.id=id;
        this.nazwa = nazwa;
        this.university = university;
    }

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String nazwa) {
        this.nazwa = nazwa;
    }
}

    @Entity
public class University {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public University(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public University() {
    }
}



  @Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student,Long> {
}

    @SpringBootApplication
public class App implements CommandLineRunner
{
    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        Student student = new Student(1L,"pawel", new University(1L,"pw"));
        Student student1 = new Student(2L,"gawel", new University(1L,"pw"));
        studentRepository. save(student);
        studentRepository.save(student1);
    }
}
```

Why that code with manual setting of student id works? Why there is a problem with code when i use @generatedValue?

@Result
The difference was because when  @GeneratedValue is used, hibernate create queries of save, comparatively when i was assigning id manually, hibernate first check  if entity exist in database if yes, entity gets updated if not hibernate save it for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

You have no sequence generator defined. You can do it in your database, then simply use (assuming its name is "my_seq"):

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq",sequenceName="my_seq")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq")
```

I can see, that you're using MySQL, then you can use the identity generation method:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

together with `auto_increment` in your id column definition:

```
create table student(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    ...
)
```

Edit:

Try saving the university first. Set this as body of your `run` method:

```
University uni = new University(1L,"pw");
University savedUni = universityRepository.save(uni);
Student student = new Student("pawel", savedUni);
Student student1 = new Student("gawel", savedUni);
studentRepository.save(student);
studentRepository.save(student1);
```

If you are saving only `Student`s everyone with the new instance of `University`, then `Student`s entity are cascading and inserting that instance every time, so that constraints are violated. This happens, because `new University(1L,"pw")` is not managed and hibernate treats it as a new entity - and because you did not provide an id - it was set as some default (`0L`). Using `University savedUni = universityRepository.save(uni);` makes hibernate recognize the entity, so that no additional insert is done.

Comment: i set as You suggested but excepton stay the same
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

Comment: did you add auto_increment to column definition?

Comment: I have updated the answer with an instruction how to do that

Comment: my student class now: public class Student { @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) private Long id;    is it what you meant?

Comment: Dude, no... `auto_increment` in table definition. Read the answer one more time, please.

Comment: ok, now i understand that part. I use spring data so it is by spring set to auto_increment. This is a log: "create table student (id bigint not null auto_increment,..." . I set @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) as you suggested but the problem remains the same. Yes I use mysql

Comment: Ok, thanks, I have updated the answer, can you try now?

Comment: than it works but i am still wondering why it doesnt work the way i coded. As i mentioned my code start working when i remove "@generated value in student and set id manually: Student student = new Student(1L,"pawel", new University(1L,"pw"));
        Student student1 = new Student(2L,"gawel", new University(1L,"pw"));  But why? what is the difference between @generatedValue and manual setting id in student class? i wanted to avoid seperate save of university class. BTW thans for help ;)

Comment: I have added explanation in the answer, check i out:) no problem, if it helps, consider upvoting / marking as correct to help others with the same problem.

Comment: I am not sure if you see my concern about working code where i set student id manually. I edited my question, please check if its more clear

Comment: It's because when you used `@GeneratedValue` you did not give any id (hibernate assumes it's generated by db), it was set for the entity as default long (`0L`), but when you gave an id, it did not violate the constraint.

Comment: if this works, please consider marking as correct / upvoting.